# how does the apt-get progress bar work/how is it implemented?

Tags: terminal, progress-bar, apt-get

How does the apt-get progress bar work, it shows up in the console which, as far as I understand it, is a highly limiting environment and yet there aren't any residual effects. The only way I have seen to make a progress bar in a terminal is to do carriage returns which, even on the fastest of computers, results in lots of flicker on longer displays. This might be me being an idiot since I mainly use windows and only rarely use the linux terminal, but if not then I would like to know how the apt-get progress bar works so I can incorporate a similar design into my own programs.

Comment: i would love to know this as well, but im experienced linux.